# trying to prove or disprove $C$ for the sequence: $\forall c \in N : S_n = n^2 - n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing

The following shows the question I am working on.

[image]

However, I have no idea where to begin

Answer (score 0):

The point here is that  the choice of $m$ comes at the very end. We can always choose $m=\frac {k^{165}+165} {S_k}$ so that the inequality holds. [ We can take $i=1$].  Hence $C$ is true.